# Corona sdk - gameNetwork + game center iOs not working

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk, game-center

I'm getting crazy about this issue. Just following the guide of how to using gameNetwork with no success. Here is my code:

main.lua

```
gameNetwork = require "gameNetwork"
loggedIntoGC = false


local function initCallback( event )
if event.data then
    loggedIntoGC = true
    -- native.showAlert( "Success!", "User has logged into Game Center", { "OK" } )
else
    loggedIntoGC = false
    gameNetwork.request( "loadScores", 
        { leaderboard={ category="com.mycompany.mygame.myrankingid", 
        playerScope="Global", timeScope="AllTime", range={1,50} },
        listener=requestCallback } )

    -- native.showAlert( "Fail", "User is not logged into Game Center", { "OK" } )
end
end

-- function to listen for system events
local function onSystemEvent( event ) 
if event.type == "applicationStart" then
    gameNetwork.init( "gamecenter", initCallback )
    return true
end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystemEvent )
```

Then just to test:

```
if loggedIntoGC then 
gameNetwork.request( "setHighScore", 
  { localPlayerScore={ category="com.mycompany.mygame.myrankingid", value=t.text }, 
  listener=requestCallback } ); 
end

if loggedIntoGC then 
gameNetwork.request( "loadScores", 
  { leaderboard={ category="com.mycompany.mygame.myrankingid", playerScope="Global", timeScope="AllTime", range={1,50} }, 
  listener=requestCallback } ); 
end

if loggedIntoGC then 
gameNetwork.show( "leaderboards", 
  { leaderboard={ category="com.mycompany.mygame.myrankingid", timeScope="AllTime" } }     ); 
end
```

Trying example on device do nothing, just login game center user...

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

In your `initCallback`, if `event.data` is false this means gameNetwork have failed to login to the server, so making a request for scores will fail. You should check the error:

```
local function scoresCallback(event)
    print("Got " .. #event.data .. " scores")
    print("Local player score: " .. event.localPlayerScore)
end

local function initCallback( event )
    if event.data then
        loggedIntoGC = true
        print('Successful login')
        gameNetwork.request( "loadScores", 
        { 
            leaderboard = { 
                category = "com.mycompany.mygame.myrankingid", 
                playerScope = "Global", 
                timeScope = "AllTime", 
                range={1,50} 
            },
            listener = scoresCallback,
        } )

    else
        loggedIntoGC = false
        print("Error init game center: ", event.errorMessage)
    end
end
```

Run the above code in the sim and look at console; run it on the device and look at log file. This will likely give clue to issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but login is still working, the problem is leaderboard that is always empty...

Comment: @Eusthace Can you run the updated code from updated answer and say what happens in simulator console output, and on device via log file.